# "Unable to connect" to local website running Apache 2 / PHP

Tags: linux-mint, apache-httpd, php

I am trying to connect to a PHP page on my local machine via Apache2 using an alias "myweb" as follows:

```
$ ifconfig
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d8:cb:8a:99:c4:f6  
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f994:c2a8:b850:d97c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:115080 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:72867 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:133785636 (133.7 MB)  TX bytes:7441492 (7.4 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:9199 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9199 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:1506579 (1.5 MB)  TX bytes:1506579 (1.5 MB)
```

myweb.conf:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.2:80>
    ServerName myweb
    ServerAdmin xxxxxx@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/myweb/http"
    Alias /media /home/daniel/venvs/nook/myapi/media
    <Directory "/home/daniel/venvs/nook/myapi/media">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SetEnv devmode 1
</VirtualHost>
```

When I go to "http://myweb/login.php" I get the message "Unable to connect" in Firefox. I am using Linux Mint 18.1, Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) and PHP 7.0.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.1. Note my computer is connected to a modem / router, but if I turn on my Wi-Fi repeater then I get redirected to "http://www.tplinkrepeater.net". The alias "myweb" used to work, but something has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to `/etc/hosts`:

```
192.168.1.2  myweb
```